# How to save data from hadoop to database using python

Tags: python, xml, database, hadoop

I am using hadoop to process an xml file,so i had written mapper file , reducer file in python.

suppose the input need to process is **test.xml**

```
<report>
 <report-name name="ALL_TIME_KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT"/>
 <date-range date="All Time"/>
 <table>
  <columns>
   <column name="campaignID" display="Campaign ID"/>
   <column name="adGroupID" display="Ad group ID"/>
  </columns>
  <row campaignID="79057390" adGroupID="3451305670"/>
  <row campaignID="79057390" adGroupID="3451305670"/>
 </table>
</report>
```

**mapper.py** file

```
import sys
import cStringIO
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml

if __name__ == '__main__':
    buff = None
    intext = False
    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.find("<row") != -1:
        .............
        .............
        .............
        print '%s\t%s'%(campaignID,adGroupID )
```

**reducer.py** file

```
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for line in sys.stdin:
        print line.strip()
```

I had run the hadoop with following command

```
bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.4.jar 
- file /path/to/mapper.py file -mapper /path/to/mapper.py file 
-file /path/to/reducer.py file -reducer /path/to/reducer.py file 
-input /path/to/input_file/test.xml 
-output /path/to/output_folder/to/store/file
```

When i run the above command hadoop is creating an output file at output path in the format we mentioned in `reducer.py` file correctly with required data

Now after all what i am trying to do is, i dont want to store output data in a text file created as default by haddop when i run above command, instead i want to save the data in to a `MYSQL` database

so i had written some python code in `reducer.py` file that writes the data directly to `MYSQL` database , and tried to run the above command by removing the output path as below

```
bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.4.jar 
- file /path/to/mapper.py file -mapper /path/to/mapper.py file 
-file /path/to/reducer.py file -reducer /path/to/reducer.py file 
-input /path/to/input_file/test.xml
```

And i am getting the error something like below

```
12/11/08 15:20:49 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Missing required option: output
Usage: $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar \
          $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar [options]
Options:
  -input    <path>     DFS input file(s) for the Map step
  -output   <path>     DFS output directory for the Reduce step
  -mapper   <cmd|JavaClassName>      The streaming command to run
  -combiner <cmd|JavaClassName> The streaming command to run
  -reducer  <cmd|JavaClassName>      The streaming command to run
  -file     <file>     File/dir to be shipped in the Job jar file
  -inputformat TextInputFormat(default)|SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat|JavaClassName Optional.
  -outputformat TextOutputFormat(default)|JavaClassName  Optional.
   .........................
   .........................
```

1. After all my doubt is how to save the data in `Database` after processing the files ?
2. In which file(mapper.py/reducer.py ? ) can we write the code that writes the data in to database
3. which command is used to run hadoop for saving data in to database, becuase when i removed the output folder path in the hadoop command, it is showing an error.

Can anyone please help me to solve the above problem.............

**Edited**

**Processed followed**

1. Created `mapper` and `reducer` files as above that reads the xml file and creates a text file at some folder by `hadoop command`

   Ex: The folder where the text file(the result of xml file processing with hadoop command) is below

   /home/local/user/Hadoop/xml_processing/xml_output/part-00000

Here the xml file size is `1.3 GB` and after processing with hadoop the size of the `text file` created is `345 MB`

Now what all i want to do is `reading the text file in the above path and saving data to the mysql database` as fast as possible.

I have tried this with basic python, but is is taking some `350 sec` to process text file and saving to mysql database.

1. Now as indicated by nichole downloaded sqoop and unzipped at some path like below

   /home/local/user/sqoop-1.4.2.bin__hadoop-0.20

And entered in to `bin` folder and typed `./sqoop` and i received the below error

```
sh-4.2$ ./sqoop
Warning: /usr/lib/hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Try 'sqoop help' for usage.
```

Also i have tried below

```
./sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/Xml_Data --username root --table PerformaceReport --export-dir /home/local/user/Hadoop/xml_processing/xml_output/part-00000 --input-fields-terminated-by '\t'
```

**Result**

```
Warning: /usr/lib/hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

12/11/27 11:54:57 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
12/11/27 11:54:57 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
12/11/27 11:54:57 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:636)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:525)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:548)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:191)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:175)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:262)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1235)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1060)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:82)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:64)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:97)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:57)
```

Whether the above sqoop command is useful for the functionality of reading the text file and saving in to database ? , because we have to process from text file and insert in to database !!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I code all my hadoop MR jobs in python. Let me just say that you need not use python for moving data. **Use Sqoop** : http://sqoop.apache.org/

Sqoop is an open-source tool that allows users to extract data from a relational database into Hadoop for further processing. And its very simple to use. All you need to do is

1. Download and configure sqoop
2. Create your mysql table schema
3. Specify hadoop hdfs file name, result table name and column seperator.

Read this for more info : http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html

**Advantage** of using sqoop is that we can now convert our hdfs data to any type of relational database (mysql,derby,hive,etc) and vice versa with a single line command

For your use case, please do necessary changes :

mapper.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.find("<row") != -1 :
            words=line.split(' ')
            campaignID=words[1].split('"')[1]
            adGroupID=words[2].split('"')[1]
            print "%s:%s:"%(campaignID,adGroupID)
```

streaming command

```
bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.4.jar - file /path/to/mapper.py file -mapper /path/to/mapper.py file -file /path/to/reducer.py file -reducer /path/to/reducer.py file -input /user/input -output /user/output
```

mysql

```
create database test;
use test;
create table testtable ( a varchar (100), b varchar(100) );
```

sqoop

```
./sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --username root --table testnow --export-dir /user/output --input-fields-terminated-by ':'
```

**Note** :

1. Please change mapper as per your need
2. I have used ':' as my column seperator in both the mapper and in sqoop command. Change as per needed.
3. Sqoop tutorials : I have personally followed Hadoop:The Definitive Guide (Oreilly) as well as http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html.

Comment: k i have started using sqoop and trying to install it please have a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411525/sqoop-installation-error-on-fedora-15

Comment: Actually here i want to process xml file and store data from xml file to database(in reverse actually),can u provide me a basic example on processing xml file with sqoop and saving data in to database ?

Comment: I am assuming you were able to setup sqoop, if not I will help you with it. The hdfs output file should be sent to mysql directly using sqoop. Kindly reply whether this has helped you

Comment: k i am clear until using hadoop command for saving to /user/output folder, now where i can use ./sqoop command ? I have tried by typing it in terminal but it says sh: "./sqoop: No such file or directory" , also i have tried from the folder where i unzip sqoop and i got same result as above

Comment: Check in /bin folder where you unzipped sqoop. If it still isnt then there must be a problem with your sqoop setup, will help you with it once you tell me what errors you get on running $SQOOP_FOLDER/bin/sqoop. Hope this helps, if it did please upvote the answer and mark it as resolved !

Comment: i have edited my code and explained the process i have followed, please have a look at at above code ?

Comment: You do not have the mysql connector. Download mysql- 
connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar from http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ and move it to $SQOOP_FOLDER/lib

Comment: yup downloaded and placed in lib folder,and when i run again i got the following error, please have a look at this link http://pastebin.com/h4JzD9Ea

Comment: You forgot to add  --input-fields-terminated-by 'your_delimiter'

Comment: k Now this is the complete command "./sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/Xml_Data --table PerformaceReport  --export-dir /home/local/user/Hadoop/hadoop-1.0.4/xml_processing/xml_output_today --username root --password redhat -m 1 --input-fields-terminated-by '\t' ", and now i am getting the error as here http://pastebin.com/W0T1gNVn

Comment: It is probably not tab delimited properly. Can you run what I have given and see if it works. I want to know if its sqoop problem or string delimitation problem

Comment: yeah i had run the command by copying urs and made changes for export directory folder path, username, password and i got that result actually

Comment: for example i had exported data from database table in to textfile bu using sqoop command and tried to reinsert in to database using sqoop command and this too not working and displaying same result

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20235/discussion-between-nicole-hu-and-kour-ipm)

Answer (score 1):

The best place to write your data to the database would from OutputFormat. Reducer level writing can be done but not the best thing to do.

If you had written mapper and reducer in Java you could have made use of [DBOutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/mapreduce/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/db/DBOutputFormat.html).

So you can write a custom OutputFormat which meets your data output format (key, value) of reducer to sink the data to MySQL.

Read [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#outputformat) tutorial on Yahoo Developer Network on how to write a custom Output Format

Comment: :I am using hadoop with python,so can u please suggest in pythonic view ?

Comment: Then you better alter your reducer.py to sink data to database directly because it is stage just above OutputFormat. Use a dummy location for -output parameter so that the above command doesn't fail.

Comment: Furthermore use a NullOutputFormat for -outputformat parameter to ignore output.