# sqoop installation error on fedora 15

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to install sqoop on my machine,i downloaded tar file from [here](http://apache.techartifact.com/mirror/sqoop/1.4.2/)

and trying to install by seeing [here](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/Sqoop+Installation)

So when i tried the below command i getting the error as below

```
[root@065 local]# (cd /usr/local/ && sudo tar \-zxvf _</home/local/user/Desktop/sqoop-1.4.2.bin__hadoop-0.20.tar.gz>_)
```

**Error**

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

What wrong with the above command ?

Can anyone please let me know the easiest way of installing sqoop ?

Actually i had a `1GB xml` file that need to be processed and saved in to MYSQL database, i used hadoop with python for doing this but it is taking `hrs` to process and save, so i decided to use sqoop and process the xml file and save the data in to database

Also please let me know the basic and easy tutorial to work with sqoop

Also please provide me a basic code that process the xml file and saves data in to database as i am newbie to sqoop.

Answer (score 1):

Validate the tar by just executing this command

```
ls -l /home/local/user/Desktop/
```

and check the file size whether it is consistent with the 4.6M or close

after that just try running the following

```
tar -zxvf /home/local/user/Desktop/sqoop-1.4.2.bin__hadoop-0.20.tar.gz
```

Then copy to /usr/local/

**UPDATE:**

You have copied and pasted the exact command from cloudera documentation.

_<path_to_sqoop.tar.gz>_ you don't need _ < and > _  those are used for placeholder for the documentation.

Run this

```
(cd /usr/local/ && sudo tar \-zxvf /home/local/user/Desktop/sqoop-1.4.2.bin__hadoop-0.20.tar.gz)
```

Comment: k i have the command is successfully executed, but how to test whether it is installed or not?. i have typed "sqoop help" to check, but its displaying "no command found"

Comment: navigate to sqoop extracted directory /usr/local/ or /home/local/user/Desktop/ and type ./bin/sqoop. Alternatively you can set the sqoop/bin in your PATH environment variable to type sqoop from anywhere.

Comment: k i tried ./bin/sqoop from the sqoop file directory and its displaying "Error: /usr/lib/hadoop does not exist! Please set $HADOOP_HOME to the root of your Hadoop installation."Actually i installed hadoop by downloading the tar file and unzipping it at a specified path(I dint installed hadoop just unzipped the tar file thats all).The path for hadoop main folder where i unzipped is "/home/local/user/name/Hadoop/hadoop-1.0.4/".I had set the path for $Hadoop_Home in /home/local/user/name/Desktop/sqoop-1.4.2.bin__hadoop-0.20/conf/sqoop-env-template.sh as "/home/local/user/name/Hadoop/hadoop-1.0.4/"

Comment: It should be HADOOP_HOME not Hadoop_Home. and you would need to configure Hadoop by editing configuration files in HADOOP_HOME/conf directory. Follow this http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

Answer (score 1):

Please also add $HADOOP_HOME in your ~/.bash_rc file.

```
vim ~/.bash_rc
```

Add this to your bash_rc file :

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/local/user/name/Hadoop/hadoop-1.0.4/
```

Save your file and then perform

```
source ~/.bash_rc .
```

Also, you need to copy sqoop-env-templat‌​e.sh to sqoop-env.sh. As the name suggests, it is only a template :

```
cp /home/local/user/name/Desktop/sqoop-1.4.2.bin__hadoop-0.20/conf/sqoop-env-templat‌​e.sh /home/local/user/name/Desktop/sqoop-1.4.2.bin__hadoop-0.20/conf/sqoop-env.sh
```

Edit sqoop-env.sh:

```
vim /home/local/user/name/Desktop/sqoop-1.4.2.bin__hadoop-0.20/conf/sqoop-env.sh
```

Add the following line to sqoop-env.sh:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/local/user/name/Hadoop/hadoop-1.0.4/
```

Now test sqoop :

```
./bin/sqoop help
```

To make your life simpler , you can also add sqoop to your bashrc file